# Web browsers removing slash in URL

Tags: dns, browser, apache-http-server, url, ubuntu-server

I have a URL (http://www.example.com/). Whenever me, a user, or a bot(search indexers) enter (http://www.example.com/Folder) the domain automatically redirects to (http://www.example.comFolder). All browsers are removing this slash. This also applies to files and subfolders, the slash after .com is removed and the user is redirected to their default DNS search site.

What can I configure, either with DNS or on my server, to prevent the root slash from disappearing?

My Server is configured:

- Ubuntu 14.04 VPS
- Running Apache, PHP, MySQL
- Domain purchased through NameCheap
- Site uses CloudFlare DNS

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This problem can't be with the DNS side of things, so you can strike issues related to Namecheap and Cloudflair off your list.  Its not really possible to advise without knowing your configuration, but this most likely has to do with redirect code in your apache config.

Answer (score 0):

Only a half-answer, but it sounds like you have some "broken" redirection code running server-side. I would check very carefully in the "Network" pane of your favorite browser dev-tools, for instance, to verify the redirect is coming from the server.

Assuming it is, it depends on the web server software, or other software you're running on your website.

E.g., Apache servers can do redirects via `.htaccess` files, or in the configuration.

Not very thorough, but hopefully I've given you enough to "google" on, until someone else answers.